# Merge array rows based on the first digit in a column

Tags: matlab, join, merge

I have two arrays, `A` and `B`. The first digit of each row is the serial number.

How do I combine `A` and `B` to have an array `C`, such that all rows in `A` with the same serial number in `B` are concatenated horizontally?

```
A = [ 12345;
      47542;
      32673;
      65436;
      75343;
      23496;
      54765 ]
B = [ 23566;
      33425;
      65438;
      75354 ]

y = ismember(A(:,1), B(:,1), 'rows');
t=find(y);
C= [A(t,1:12),B(t,1:12)];
```

I need `C` to be:

```
C = [ 12345, 00000;
      23496, 23566;
      32673, 33425;
      47542, 00000;
      54765, 00000;
      65436, 00000;
      75343, 75354]
```

Comment: So by "similarity" you mean the first two digits of the serial number have to be the same? What happens when more than one of these near-matches exists between `A` and `B`? What happens when there's a near match *within* one or both of `A` and `B`?

Comment: If there are more than one matches, I expect that there will be an additional column to C but in the case under consideration and based on the data available, there can only be one match.

Comment: The first element of each rows are integers and they are unique for the data under consideration.

Comment: *The First Digit of each row represent the serial number in A and B

Comment: Why 65438 (array B) is not associated with 65436 (array A) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only the first digit, we only need to check if the first digit (i.e. `floor(A/1e4)`) matches `0` to `9`, and index accordingly...

```
% Add some zeros at the front to make indexing work with the unmatched ismember outputs
Az = [zero(; A]; Bz = [0; B];  
% Find the indices for 0 to 9 within the first digits of A and B 
[~,ia] = ismember( 0:9, floor( A/1e4 ) );
[~,ib] = ismember( 0:9, floor( B/1e4 ) );
% Assign to C and discard unmatched rows
C = [Az(ia+1), Bz(ib+1)];
C( all( C==0, 2 ), : ) = [];
```

Note that keeping things numeric with the `floor` operation should always be preferable to flipping between numeric and character data with things like `num2str`...

---

**Edit**

You changed the scope of the question by commenting with new data. Here is the same method, written to be more generic so it handles `A` and `B` with more columns and different magnitude IDs

```
% Add some zeros at the front to make indexing work with the unmatched ismember outputs
Az = [zeros(1,size(A,2)); A]; Bz = [zeros(1,size(A,2)); B]; 
% Function for getting first digit
f = @(x) floor(x./(10.^floor(log10(x))));
% Find the indices for 0 to 9 within the first digits of A and B 
[~,ia] = ismember( 0:9, f(A(:,1)) );
[~,ib] = ismember( 0:9, f(B(:,1)) );
% Assign to C and discard unmatched rows
C = [Az(ia+1,:), Bz(ib+1,:)];
C( all( C==0, 2 ), : ) = [];
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when comparing for indices from zero to nine why are you including ten? Wouldnt ten be as one as the leading digit is also one in both cases?

Comment: can be generalized with `f = @(x) floor(x./(10.^floor(log10(x))))`, nice way to get the result btw.

Comment: Hi Obchardon,
I applied the same code to this data but got an error. Please any possible modification
A = [3,0.0068,0.046,90,0.00;
     4,0.014,0.063,36.64,1.51;
     6,0.0063,0.044,90,0.00;
     7,0.40,0.20,4.99,58.78;
     8,0.017,0.069,0.00,90];
B =  [1,0.034,0.072,55.85,-13.00;
      2,0.012,0.051,79.95,-114.65;
      3,0.14,0.12,20.68,113.77;
      4,0.00,0.045,90.00,0.00;
      6,0.015,0.054,16.77,107.71;
      9,0.44,0.055,33.45,50.37];

Comment: @Uche See my edited answer, and in future please edit your question rather than pasting unformatted code in multiple comments.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your response

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be the following, extract the leading digits of both arrays and compare those:

```
  a=num2str(A)-'0';
  b=num2str(B)-'0';
  [ida,idb]=ismember(a(:,1),b(:,1));
```

Now get the sorting index of `A`

```
  [~,ids]=sort(a(:,1));
```

Create output array

```
  C=zeros(size(A,1),2);
```

Finally assign and sort output

```
  C(:,1)=A;
  C(ida,2)=B(idb(idb>0));
  %sort result
  C=C(ids,:)
```

Comment: Much nicer solution than mine. Totally forgot about the "two return value option" of `ismember`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the whole script. At first glance, I couldn't find a solution without using loops.

```
A = [ 12345;
      47542;
      32673;
      65436;
      75343;
      23496;
      54765; ]

B = [ 23566;
      33425;
      65438;
      75354; ]

A = sort(A);                              % Sort A and B.
B = sort(B);                             

A_str = int2str(A);                       % Convert integers to chars.
B_str = int2str(B);

A_sn = A_str(:, 1);                       % Extract first columns.
B_sn = B_str(:, 1);                       % Basically, these are the serial numbers.                                              

C = zeros(size(A, 1), size(A, 2) * 2);    % Initialize C.

C(:, 1) = A;                              % First column of C is just A.

for i = 1:length(A_sn)                    % For all serial numbers in A...
  for j = 1:length(B_sn)                  % For all serial numbers in B...
    if (A_sn(i) == B_sn(j))               % Check if serial number in B equals the serial number in A.
      C(i, 2) = B(j);                     % If so, set i-th row in C to the corresponding value in B.
    end
  end
end

C
```

Results in:

```
A =
    12345
    47542
    32673
    65436
    75343
    23496
    54765

B =
    23566
    33425
    65438
    75354

C =
    12345       0
    23496   23566
    32673   33425
    47542       0
    54765       0
    65436   65438
    75343   75354
```

Comment: From your `endif` and `int2str(B)(:, 1)` notation, I assume you're using Octave. Neither of these are valid MATLAB syntax, so they're not really valid in an answer to a MATLAB question (without the Octave tag). I already edited your `end` statements, but you'll need an intermediate variable assignment for the bracketing issues.

Comment: Indeed, I'm currently using Octave. (MATLAB's running of my second machine.) I corrected the `endif` statements by myself, I forgot that in my initial answer. (Maybe, you were faster!?) But I was absolutely sure, that `int2str(B)(:, 1)` is proper MATLAB notation. I will pay more attention to that issue in future! Edited my post.

Comment: Normal parentheses `( )` can only come at the end of a statement, so not consecutively (the exception to the rule is dynamic indexing of tables or structs where `tbl.('ColumnName')(2)` would be allowed)